# Where can I find the View Tab Order in Visual C# Express 2010?

Tags: c#, windows-7, visual-c#-express-2010

This is a pretty basic question, but I can't seem to find it. It used to be on the View menu in Visual C# Express 2005. I could always use the properties to set the tab index manually, but it is tedious for larger forms. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. It's the last button in the layout toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Forms designer view active? You can see this option only in the designer view.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks for the help, but I think I found it on the layout toolbar, it's no longer in the View menu. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also the last button in the layout toolbar. For some reason it doesn't show up under the view menu.